# Why aren't these injected variables making it to my groovy class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In my pipeline I'm injecting aws credentials:

```
withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
credentialsId: '89h9sfh8shf98shf98he9f8sf',
accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {

    sh 'printenv'

    echo myFunc.myMeth('blah','sdjlfkdf')

}
```

myFunc looks like this:

```
class myFunc {
    static Object myMeth (String param1, String param2){    
        def env = System.getenv()
        //Print all the environment variables.
        env.each{
            println it
        }

        def ebClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder()
            .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
            .build()

    }
}
```

Looking at the output of `sh 'printenv'` I see AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are injected.

But inside of myFunc I try to echo back what envs myFunc has access to I don't see those variables and the aws api complains:

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

Is this by design? Is myFunc isolated and I need change its scope or something?

Why does sh (and other steps) have access to these vars injected by withCredtials but my groovy function does not?

I've resorted to passing them as plain text and forwarding them to the aws api. This stinks because they aren't shielded from console output and i also have to manually apply them with BasicAWSCredentials in myFunc:

```
myFunc.myMeth('blah','sdjlfkdf',env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `myMeth` to a Closure?  ie:  `static Closure<Object> myMeth = { String param1, String param2 ->`

Comment: nope just tested that and its the same result. not sure why jenkins isn't expose it to my function